# Encrypt with AES using phpseclib and decrypt with CryptoJS

Tags: node.js, encryption, aes, phpseclib, cryptojs

I'm trying to encrypt a string using phpseclib AES in CBC mode (library's default):

```
$cipher = new Crypt_AES();
$cipher->setKey('abcdefghijklmnop');
$cipher->setIV(crypt_random_string($cipher->getBlockLength() >> 3));
$cipher->encrypt("hello world")
```

Then, I need to decrypt on nodejs using CryptoJS or similar.. I've tried different libs but no luck so far. I guess the issue is kind of related to the encoded output differ from each library.

Does anyone have a working example of how to implement this interoperability scenario?

Other library such as Crypto can be used.
An example Base64 output is `MF9lCR4DaW1R0adIe03VEw==`

So the idea is to decrypt as follows:

```
var helloWorld = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt("MF9lCR4DaW1R0adIe03VEw==", key).toString();
```

Comment: Why would you use a third-party crypto library in node when there is one that's built-in and faster?

Comment: Can you give example encrypted output (e.g. in hex or base64)?

Comment: @mscdex just updated the question with some examples as you requested.  Btw, node's crypto library is also an option..

Comment: Don't you need the IV for decryption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the previously generated IV during decryption. It doesn't have to be secret, but it has to be unpredictable (which it is in your case). You can send it along with the ciphertext. A common way is to prepend it to the ciphertext and slice it off during decryption.

CryptoJS supports two types of encryption. If you pass the key as a string, it will use OpenSSL's key derivation function to derive a new key with a salt. You don't want that, because you're using an explicit key. For that, you need to pass the key as WordArray (CryptoJS' native binary data structure). Additionally, the ciphertext is expected to be either an OpenSSL formatted string or a CipherParams object:

```
var message = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({
    ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("MF9lCR4DaW1R0adIe03VEw==")
}, CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('abcdefghijklmnop'), {
    iv: iv // retrieve the IV somehow
}).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

Comment: I thought the IV was already appended to the encrypted data (ciphertext) and would be seamlessly parsed on node.. so I didn't try to set it manually. Thank you for response!

Comment: You can check this by looking at the length of the ciphertext. Base64 has a blowup ratio of 4/3. This means that the actual ciphertext length `len(b64)*3/4-paddingChars`, which is in your case `24*3/4-2 = 18 - 2 = 16`. 16 is the block size of AES and since CBC is a non-streaming mode, it must produce at least a block. So there is no place for the IV to be.